# value of 1 dimensional array of string cannot be converted to String

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am trying to assign values of array to a string, following is the code:

```
oDocument1.IdentifierCode = lstFundIdentifiers.ToArray()
```

where IdentifierCode is a string while lstFundIdentifiers is declared as

`ByVal lstFundIdentifiers As List(Of String).`

I am not sure as to what is going wrong.

Comment: how can an array of string be assigned to a string? you might want to use array index to assign to a string

Comment: So previously it was something like this

oDocument.FundServCodes = lstFundServCodes.ToArray()
and FundServCodes is String while lstFundServCodes is same List(of String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String <> String()

Trying to assign an array to a string is like trying to put 4 tires on a unicycle. An array (or list) is a collection of objects, in your case, strings.

You can do this: `yourArray(1) = yourString` or `yourString = yourArray(0)`, but you can't do this: `yourString = yourArray`.

### EDIT in response to your comment:

*"So previously it was something like this oDocument.FundServCodes = lstFundServCodes.ToArray()"*

FundServCodes is an array itself, which is why that would work. You can easily confirm this by going to the class and looking at the FundServCodes property.

### EDIT 2:

These are basic programming concepts. Maybe you should go read up on collections, data types, objects, etc. There are 1000's of programming books and tutorials for all skill levels out there. Look one up and go through it.